# Scatter Plot with ILNumerics graphical issue?

Tags: c#, plot, scatter-plot, ilnumerics

I'm currently trying to plot a few points on a 3D plot window using ILNumerics.
This works actually quite good but as soon as I rotate the plot it cuts off the labels in the background...

Here is my code

```
        float[,] a = new float[2, 3] { { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f }, { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f } };
        ILArray<float> B = a;

        var scene = new ILScene {
            new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false) {
                new ILPoints {
                    Positions = B,
                    Size = 4,
                }
            }
        };

        ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
```

This is an image of whats happening:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd2cqzsp8kqc8d5/plot.png

I hope you guys have a suggestion for this problem...
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is there an error message? What happens, when you double click on the plot?

Comment: If your code is not defined in the panel.Load event handler - did you try to add ilPanel1.Scene.Configure() at the end?

Comment: no there is no error message Haymo. I can rotate it and everything but it doesnt show the hole cube... the code snippet is also defined in the ILpanel.load(). What does ilPanel1.Scene.Configure() do ?

Comment: well... the ilPanel1.Scene.Configure() obviously did the job with the axis... but now I have the cube, can rotate it and it displays only one single red point in the middle of the cube. doesnt matter which example of the website I try

Comment: This is, because you have two points defined in your example but they both lay on exactly the same place: 1,2,3. Not sure, how this relates to the website you mentioned, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After any modification of buffer data Configure() needs to be called on the affected node or any node on the path up to the root node. The only exception to that rule: if your code rests in the load event handler for the ILPanel, ILNumerics calls this for you automatically.

Obviously, your code is defined somewhere else - not in that handler. So you must follow the common rule and add ilPanel1.Scene.Configure() manually.

Comment: my code is definately defined in "private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)" which is related to the event handler. well, it works now so thanks to everyone who helped me!!